# Getting specific app pool's worker process in PowerShell returns value but process is already stopped

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool, get-childitem, web-administration

I have multiple websites - each on a separate app pool.
The app pool I'm referring to has 1 worker process.
After stopping the app pool, I'm trying to wait and verify that the worker process has stopped.

```
$appPoolName = $appPool.name;
    
    Write-Host "appPoolName: $appPoolName";

    $w3wp = Get-ChildItem "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName\WorkerProcesses\";

    while($w3wp -and $retrys -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Host "w3wp value is: $w3wp";

        Start-Sleep -s 10;
        $retrys--;
        
        $w3wp = Get-ChildItem "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName\WorkerProcesses\";

        Write-Host "w3wp value(2) is: $w3wp";

        if(-not $w3wp)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

The print of both values is always "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement", even when I see the process is stopped and no longer in Task Manager.

Also strange: When I open another PowerShell session while the code runs and call

```
 $w3wp = Get-ChildItem "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName\WorkerProcesses\";
```

w3wp has no value (because it is no longer exist).

Any ideas why the value isn't changing?
Or maybe how to do that differently?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I also think it is caused by the cache, you can reset the iis through the iisreset command, and then try again. right-click on cmd.exe and select run as administrator, at the command prompt, type `IISRESET`, press Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `IIS:` provider is caching data. I dont know of a fix, but heres a couple of alternatives:

use WMI from powershell:
`gwmi -NS 'root\WebAdministration' -class 'WorkerProcess' | select AppPoolName,ProcessId`

Run appcmd
`appcmd list wp`

Comment: It worked for me (just swiched the aliases to the actual commands: `$w3wp = Get-WmiObject -NS 'root\WebAdministration' -class 'WorkerProcess' | Select-Object AppPoolName,ProcessId | Where-Object { $_.AppPoolName -eq $appPoolName }`. Thanks!